# How do you encrypt an SSD on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, encryption, ssd

I have mounted an internal SSD and I don't know how to encrypt it without formating the partition and deleting all data on it. If anyone has a solution i would love to hear it.

*Note: I am using the SSD for storage and I am not booting off it.*

Thanks for any comments, votes or answers.

Comment: Note: there should be no difference between HDDs and SSDs when doing this.

Comment: Encryption is destructive, you have to move your data off the disc, encrypt the disc, and move your data back.